# Is ChannelFactory with async methods in .NET 4.5 supported?

Tags: wcf, async-await, channelfactory

I'm in the process of converting our WCF services to use async programming. As expected the interface looks like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task<string> DoSomething(string request);
}
```

On the client side I'm not creating a service reference from Visual Studio. Since I own both client and server I just share the interface with the client, then I create (and cache) a ChannelFactory. To invoke the method asynchronously I use the expected syntax:

```
IFoo clientChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
bool result = await clientChannel.DoSomething("Hello World");
```

My question is: Is the IClientChannel generated by the ChannelFactory really using the async features underneath? I mean, can I be sure there's no thread blocked waiting for the server response?

Comment: Why don't you use JustDecompile/dotPeek/Reflector and see for yourself?

Comment: Try running [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324995/cancel-a-long-running-task-over-wcf-from-client/15330417#15330417) in LinqPad and tell me what you see...

Comment: @StephenCleary the code that deserialises the WCF Task is going to be pretty deep in the dotnet 4.5 library (assuming its even MSIL that does it). I'm not sure I would wish that sort of decompilation adventure on anyone. It would be easier to design some experimental test code.

Comment: @Aron: I'm having a hard time thinking of a test that would prove any particular method is in fact using fully asynchronous calls. I.e., the code you linked to wouldn't do that.

Comment: Replace the binding with httpbinding run in the debugger then break point, check the thread window.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ClientBase code, async calls all boil down to:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannel.cs,0353de22100bb396

There doesn't seem to be any reason to think the thread would block waiting for a network response.